# mysql encryption key storage on file

Tags: mysql

I have a MYSQL server on a linux server. I am using AES encryption functions to store data in the DB server. Commands are like this ones:

```
INSERT into userc (name, town) VALUES ('john',AES_ENCRYPT('nebraska', 'usa2010'));
SELECT CAST(AES_DECRYPT(town, 'usa2010') AS CHAR(50)) town_decrypt from userc;
```

My concern on this kind of encryption is that everything needed to access my data is travelling in clear, so a sniffer or a Debug level log are capable of capturing everything.

Is there a way of not sending the key in the command, but having it stored on a file (/home/user/key.txt) and so calling the encryption in a way similar to this:

```
INSERT into userc (name, town) VALUES ('john',AES_ENCRYPT('nebraska', key1));
```

Where key1 is the reference to the file where the key is stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was more a DB question, so I posted it there and got a solution. The proposal, now being tested is to create a user defined function (UDF) in C and load it in mysql. This, being coded in C can perform any action I need, reading a file, and geting the key from it, based on a parameter it got.

Of course this file has to be protected in some way so it is not exposed.